# How to override java.util.logging.Logger to my private logger?

Tags: java, logging

I have code fetched from `jar` that uses `java.util.logging.Logger`.

Jar contains about 1000 logger usages and each class start from:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class.getName());
```

I want to handle all logs there, means, to point them to my Logger usage and not to `java.util.logging.Logger`.

Therefore I wrote my own logger.

So instead:

```
LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error sleeping", e);
```

I can write:

```
 MyLogger.toLog(TLogLevel.WFS_ERROR, "Monkey", "Error sleeping", e );
```

The problem is I need run over all java files and replace with mine.

Messy way, hmm

Does anyone know how can by easy way to convert `java.util.logging.Logger` to `com.boo.MyLogger`?

Thanks,

Comment: That problem is a consequence of j.u.l being hard-wired into the Java class libraries. All other logging libraries can be bridged easily (and without real overhead). But why aren't you using one of the established logging frameworks? They do handle these issues.

Comment: What code have you written. Post it

Comment: I agree with @Thilo.  There's no real justification for implementing your own logger APIs.  It is certainly not in the interest of people who might want to use your code.

Comment: @StephenC: He may have an interesting custom logger *implementation*, though. But that should use the SLF4J API.

Comment: @Thilo - if you had said that he had custom appenders etc for one of the existing frameworks I would have agreed.  But the world doesn't need another framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SLF4J project has [a jul-to-slf4j bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) that can be used to redirect java.util.logging.Logger calls to SLF4J. You could use that (by making your MyLogger implement the interface defined by SLF4J).

Note that, however, unlike all other logging libraries, j.u.l. is hard-wired into the Java class libraries and cannot be bridged without a performance penalty.

Also, I don't know what you are doing with MyLogger, but usually there is no need to write your own. There are plenty of logging implementations to choose from, and they can be configured in many different ways. And even if you do have to write your own Logger *implementation*, you should use an existing *interface* (such as SLF4J which seems to most popular these days).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/):

> The Simple Logging Facade for Java or (SLF4J) serves as a simple
>   facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks, e.g.
>   java.util.logging, log4j and logback, allowing the end user to plug in
>   the desired logging framework at deployment time.

Using that you could then also use [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) (same author) to log to a common logging framework using the various bridges already available. Or, write your own, but either way you would not have to worry about replacing all that code...

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's Java 7 Logger is configurable, its implementation is simply:

```
public static Logger getLogger(String name) {
    // This method is intentionally not a wrapper around a call
    // to getLogger(name, resourceBundleName). If it were then
    // this sequence:
    //
    //     getLogger("Foo", "resourceBundleForFoo");
    //     getLogger("Foo");
    //
    // would throw an IllegalArgumentException in the second call
    // because the wrapper would result in an attempt to replace
    // the existing "resourceBundleForFoo" with null.
    LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();
    return manager.demandLogger(name);
}
```

So you can also via code set a logging level; besides declarative.

```
LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME).setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

[Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Logging/article.html#overview_create) has a nice page, also with its own Logger class.

All put together is quite workable, but maybe sometimes somewhat hard to understand.

Comment: +1. Not the nicest API in the world, but since it's included in the JVM, coding to it and learning how to configure it is a good option.